# When copying code in Android Studio it copies like square blocks

Tags: android-studio

When copying code in `Android studio` it looks different. It copies like a block. How to fix this?

In this image

[image]

I'm trying to copy code, but it's not as always does

Happy coding:)

Answer (score 2):

Try to press shift+alt+insert, and than select again.

Comment: On Mac it is holding option while selecting text!

Comment: I tried it already but no changes. Invalidate cache and restart is solved the issue. Thank you for the replies @ ChristianoBolla, @MxWild

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the previous answer I investigated it and found out how it can get turned on by accident with a mouse click, it's called Column Selection Mode.
[image]